# Can I use a multi-line function or control flow segment into the PowerShellFar editor console

Tags: powershell, far-manager

If I am running farmanager with FarNet and PowerShellFar I can bring up a console of sorts by selecting **F11 | .NET PowerShell | Editor Console**. This console is based on the far editor. I can paste snippets of powershell scripts into this console and edit them.

The only problem is if I want to use a multi-line function or control flow segment in the console. If I paste it in it has no effect. If I attempt to type one in I get an error similar to:

```
ERROR: IncompleteParseException:
Missing closing '}' in statement block.
At line:1 char:42
+ foreach ($number in 1..10 ) { $number * 7 <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (CloseBraceToken:TokenId) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndCurlyBrace
```

Is this simply a limitation of PowerShellFar?

Comment: PowerShellFar 5.0.51 supports multiline commands in editor consoles, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply a limitation of the editor console feature of PSF. The editor
console is designed for true one-liner commands in the first place.

Multiline commands are not suitable for console-like UI anyway: even if you can
input and run such a command then you cannot easily bring it back to modify and
run again.

But you still can copy/paste/invoke a snippet. Copy, paste, then select its
text in the editor console and do: *F11 | PowerShellFar | Invoke selected
code*. It's a little bit awkward but it works.

---

**UPDATE**

PowerShellFar 5.0.51 supports multiline commands in editor consoles:

- Like in ISE, `ShiftEnter` just adds a new line without invoking the command.
- `Enter` at any position of the last command area invokes the whole area code.
- As a result, it is possible to paste multiline code and invoke it by `Enter`.